# Which word best translates spark as in a spark of energy?

Tags: classical-latin, medieval-latin, contemporary-latin

Any latin, my tags aren't a mistake. The more variations the better thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any sense, the word to use is *scintilla*, 'spark' (possibly *scintillula*, though it would probably then be better translated as 'gleam').

Cicero in *de Republica* 2, 21 has:

*qui cum famulorum  numero educatus ad epulas regis adsisteret, non latuit **scintilla ingenii** quae iam tum elucebat in puero*.

Comment: I have come across so-called scintillation detectors when studying particle physics, and those are indeed based on "sparks of energy". I fully support this choice (or *scintillula* for a small spark), not only because it will be readily understandable for a number of physicists. I think the same choice will work for all eras, only with slightly different pronunciations.

Comment: @Joonas Ilmavirta Takes me back to my long-forgotten days in neutron activation analysis!